# Flutter: Updating the more recent value while the user in viewing the page with streams

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Am I thinking about this the right way?

I created a function that takes in a value from firebase, value in seconds, and convert it into hours:minutes:seconds, this works fine. I've used Streams for my function and a StreamBuilder for my text widget to display the value, but without the setState I don't know how else to always show the more recent value while the user is actively looking at the page. Without setState I would have to navigate to a different page then come back to see the UI update the most recent value.

Is using setState the correct way to go about it? Will it cause a spam of writes to firebase, causing me to go over the limit ( i have a free firebase account).

Is there a better way to always show the most updated value on screen?

```
Stream<String> printDuration() async* {
   FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen(
          (event) => someVar = event.data()!['timeActive'], 
          onError: (error) => print("Listen failed: $error")
        );

    Duration duration = Duration(seconds: someVar ?? loggedInUser.timeActive);
      String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    String _getData = "${twoDigits(duration.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
    setState(() {});
    yield _getData;
  }
```

text widget

```
StreamBuilder<String>(
                                  stream: printDuration(),
                                  builder: ((context, snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.data != null) {
                                      return Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data!.toString(): 'no data yet',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Color(0xff516395),
                                            fontSize: 26.0,
                                            letterSpacing: 2.0,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    } else {
                                      return Text('0',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Color(0xff516395),
                                            fontSize: 30.0,
                                            letterSpacing: 2.0,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          ));
                                    }
                                  }),
                                )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to call `setState`, `StreamBuilder` builds itself on the latest update. Try something like this.

```
  Stream<String> timeActive(String userUid) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(userUid)
      .snapshots()
      .map((e) => e.data()?['timeActive'])
      .map((timeActive) { <convert to hours:minutes:seconds> });
  }
```

Comment: Is there meant to be a ```;``` between the two maps?